# Pivot table without null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have the following table

```
+-----+-------+------+---------+
| ID  | NAME  | SORT |  AMOUNT |
+-----+-------+------+---------+
|   1 | sak   | A    |     200 |
|   2 | mods  | b    |     200 |
|   3 | wef   | c    |     200 |
|   4 | sak   | b    |     300 |
|   5 | mods  | a    |     210 |
+-----+-------+------+---------+
```

and I write the following code:

```
SELECT ID,A, B, C 
FROM 
(
Select ID,SORT,
 'SORT'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by ID order by ID)
             as varchar(10)) Col
from TABLE
) Temp 
pivot 
(
max (SORT)
for Col in ( A, B, C  )
)piv
```

I got this result:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| ID |  A   |  B   |  C   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  5 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+
```

But need to show the table in this way but I get NULL instead of amount.

Comment: MySQL does not support `PIVOT`. Which database are you actually using?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Comment: OK then - I removed the `mysqli` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you want one record per `sak`, with the `amount` for `a`, `b` and `c` in columns.

Here is a cross-database solution that pivots the dataset over a *fixed* list of columns using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sak,
    max(case when upper(sort) = 'A' then amount end) a,
    max(case when upper(sort) = 'B' then amount end) b,
    max(case when upper(sort) = 'C' then amount end) c
from mytable
group by sak
order by sak
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, that is nice solution and works good for me, but I need to do it with pivot function because i try to understand it. Could you please help me to do it with pivot?

Comment: @RAZ . . . It is better to understand conditional aggregation -- which is standard SQL -- rather than bespoke constructs such as `pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following too:

1. As per your structure

```
SELECT ID, A, B, C
FROM
(
Select ID,UPPER(SORT) SORT,AMOUNT
from MYTABLE
) Temp
pivot
(
max (AMOUNT)
for SORT in (A, B, C)
)piv
ORDER BY 1
```

2. Expected

```
SELECT NAME, A, B, C
FROM
(
SELECT NAME, SORT, AMOUNT
FROM MYTABLE
)T
PIVOT
(
SUM(AMOUNT) FOR SORT IN (A, B, C)
)PVT
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @column nvarchar(max)
    declare @Query nvarchar(max)
    declare @price nvarchar(max)
    declare @last nvarchar(max)
    declare @with nvarchar(10)
    DECLARE @colsWithNoNulls    NVARCHAR(MAX)

    IF @subcategory > 0
        begin
            set @with = 'and'
        end
    ELSE
        begin
            set @with = 'or'
        end

    set @column= STUFF((Select '],['+isnull(whsname,0) from OWHS WS CROSS APPLY string_split(@whs, ',') as UI WHERE WS.WhsCode = UI.value FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') +']'
    set @price= STUFF((Select  '],['+isnull(ListName,0) from OPLN PN CROSS APPLY string_split(ISNULL(@pln,0), ',') as UX WHERE ISNULL(PN.ListNum,0) = ISNULL(UX.value,0) FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') +']'
    
    set @Query='select  * from (select w.ItemCode,m.ItemName ,b.ItmsGrpNam ItemGroupName,isnull(CAST(m.usertext AS NVARCHAR(Max)),'''') SpaceOrType
    ,m.OnHand InStock,m.IsCommited Committed,m.OnOrder Ordered
    ,(m.OnHand-m.IsCommited+m.OnOrder) Available,n.ListName ListName,c.Price priceL,s.WhsName,sum(w.OnHand) Stock

    from oitw w
    right join OITM m on m.itemcode=w.itemcode
    inner join OWHS s on s.WhsCode=w.WhsCode
    inner join OITB b on b.ItmsGrpCod=m.ItmsGrpCod
    left join ITM1 c on m.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
    left join OPLN n on c.priceList = n.listNum
    left join [@CATEGORY] h on m.U_Category = h.Code
    left join [@SUBCATEGORY] i on h.Code = i.U_mainCategory
    where b.ItmsGrpCod = '''+@brand+''' or w.ItemCode like ''%'+@name+'%'' or m.ItemName like ''%'+@name+'%'' or h.Code = '''+@category+''' '+@with+' i.Code = '''+@subcategory+'''
    group by w.ItemCode,m.itemName,b.ItmsGrpNam,m.U_Category,m.U_SubCategory,CAST(m.usertext AS NVARCHAR(max)),s.WhsName,m.OnHand ,m.IsCommited,c.price,m.OnOrder,n.ListName) fg
    PIVOT (sum(priceL) for
    ListName in ('+ISNULL(@price,0)+')) as piv
    PIVOT (sum(Stock) for
    Whsname in ('+@column+')) as piv'
    EXECUTE (@Query)
END
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).